# Нет каталога aptitude

Tags: linux, debian

Я установил aptitude, изменил некоторые параметры в нем, у меня есть задание:

Достаточно скопировать файл config 
в директорию */root/.aptitude/*:
**cp -f ./aptitude/config /root/.aptitude/config**

Но у меня нет каталога */aptitude*, никак не могу найти файл */aptitude/config*
Как быть?

Comment: создать его, очевидно... и внимание на точку перед именем — это означает что он «скрытый»...

Comment: 1. `у меня есть задание`. 2. `Но у меня нет каталога… Как быть?` 3. очевидно же: обратиться к тому, кто дал задание.

Comment: @Fat-Zer , в интернете написано, *"Пользовательский файл настройки, ~/.aptitude/config. Этот файл перезаписывается, когда пользователь изменяет настройки"* , но у меня этого фала нет, я настройки в aptitude изменял, где тогда они перезаписывались?

Comment: @Nobody, по хорошей старой традиции, когда человек утверждает что-то сомнительное, но не подкрепляет это выводом команды ему не верят (в лучшем случае)... возможные причины, почему ты его не заметил после создания: 1) каталог `.aptitude` скрытый, а ты запускаешь `ls` без ключа `-a; 2) запускал и редактировал настройки `aptitude` от root'а, а пытаешься найти файл в каталоге обычного пользователя или наоборот; 3) как-то нештатно завершаешь aptitude так что он не сохраняет конфиг; 4) делаешь какую-то ещё более дурацкую ошибку.